# Where is my variable being stored? (Swift)

Tags: swift, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

One of my little experiments with Swift:

```
func store<T>(var x: T) -> (getter: (Void -> T), setter: (T -> Void)) {
    return ({ x }, { x = $0 })
}
```

`x` is a value type.

My questions are:

- Where exactly is `x` being stored (in terms of stack/heap)?
- What are the pitfalls of storing `x` like this?
- Is this safe?
- When is `x` going to be destroyed (if ever)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Parameters are passed to functions and methods by value - that means that a copy of the parameter is created and used in the function body.

Parameters received by functions and methods are immutable, which means their value cannot be changed. However the `var` modifier makes a parameter mutable - what's important to keep into account is that the *copy* of the parameter is mutable: the parameter passed to the function has no relationship with the parameter received by the function body, besides the initial copy. That said, making a parameter mutable via the `var` modifier makes it changeable, but its lifetime ends with the function body and does not affect the original parameter passed to the function.

There's another option, the `inout` modifier, which works like the `var`, but when the function returns the value is copied back into the variable passed in.

It's worth mentioning that so far I have implicitly taken value types only into account. If an instance of a reference type (class or closure) is passed to the function, as a `var` parameter, any change made through that parameter is actually done to the instance passed to the function (that's the most significant difference between value and reference types). The instance pointed by the `x` variable has the same lifetime of the parameter passed to the function.

All that said, in your case it works in a slightly different way. You are returning a closure (ok, they are 2, but that doesn't change the conclusion), and the closure captures `x`, which causes `x` to be kept alive for as long as the variable the closure is assigned to is in scope:

```
let x = 5
let (getter, setter) = store(x)
```

In the above code, when `getter` and `setter` will be deallocated, `x` (as the variable defined in the `store` function) will cease to exist too.

To answer to your questions:

1. `x` is a variable created when the `store` function is invoked. Since you are explicitly mentioning value types, then `x` should be allocated on the stack (as opposed to the heap, which should be used for reference types)
2. the pitfall is that it's deallocated when the 2 return values (which are reference types, being closure reference types) are deallocated
3. it could be useful in some niche cases, but generally I would stay away from it - note that it's my own opinion
4. already described above (when the function returns values are deallocated)

Comment: Brilliantly worded, I really appreciate the time you put into this! However, I fail to understand the justification behind the pitfall you describe.

Comment: That should be simpler: if `T` is a value type, the variable is allocated on the stack, but the closures (being reference types) on the heap. So the data is held on the stack, and kept alive by 2 instances allocated on the heap.

Comment: bear in mind that COW implementation of standard Swift Array probably stores it's data on heap even if Array itself is a value type

Comment: @MaxDesiatov: As far as I know (but I might be wrong) internally the array uses a reference type (i.e. a class) to store the data - of course nothing is visible to the developer. That means data stored on the heap

Comment: As far as I know, `inout` *isn't* passing by reference: it's copying and then copying back. (at least when used with values)

Comment: Yeah, info [here](https://twitter.com/AirspeedSwift/status/626701244455895044) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166)

Comment: @oisdk yes that's correct - thanks for pointing it out. I've fixed in the answer. I have implicitly assumed that `&` automatically translates to _reference to_ - too many years spent on C++ :)